# What word describes the dislike of non-human (extraterrestrial) species?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In this [Science fiction question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5637/45), I use the world "Racist" to describe the human predominance of the Empire, in Star Wars.

Someone suggested *xenophobic* :

> Well, this is getting a bit into anecdotal territory, but every Science Fiction piece I've read used "xenophobic" to describe those that hated other species. It may be that you need to further define "foreign." All you have to do is take the existing definitions, and extend "species" to the locality qualifier. This isn't unreasonable, and given that the whole idea is something we have not had to combat yet I find it entirely accurate.
>   – draeath

Is there any better word to define this fictional problem?

Comment: What do you mean, '__other__' extraterrestrial species?

Comment: I don't think there will be a "better" word than *xenophobia*. That's the standard word, used for antipathy towards extraterrestrials as well as just people from other countries/regions on Earth. If you wanted to exclude the latter, you could go with *anthropocentric xenophobia*, or perhaps *terracentric/geocentric*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then is "Racist" acceptable?

Comment: Sort of like using "alien" for people from other planets, but also for people from other contries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think xenophobic is the best choice. Take [this definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=xenophobic):

> **xenophobic** - having abnormal fear or hatred of the strange or foreign

Extra-terrestrials are definitely foreign and most likely strange too.

Comment: "Xenophobic" is also often applied to the dislike of humans by other humans, so it could be somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a word that doesn't necessarily imply a strong *hatred* or *fear* of another group (like [*xenophobic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/xenophobic)), but instead an elevation of one's own group to a higher level of importance, then I would lean towards [*anthropocentric*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthropocentrism) (mentioned in a comment by [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers)) as a better alternative:

> **Anthropocentric:**
>
> 1. considering human beings as the most significant entity of the universe
> 2. interpreting or regarding the world in terms of human values and experiences

Another possibility may be [*humanocentric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropocentrism#In_fiction):

> In science-fiction, *humanocentrism* is the idea that humans, as both beings and a species, are the superior sentients. Essentially the equivalent of race supremacy on a galactic scale, it entails intolerant discrimination against sentient non-humans, much like race supremacists discriminate against those not of their race. This idea is countered by anti-humanism. At times, this ideal also includes fear of and superiority over strong AIs and cyborgs, downplaying the ideas of integration, cybernetic revolts, machine rule and Tilden's Laws of Robotics.

Answer (score 2):

It seems clearest simply to say that someone is *anti-alien*. Not only does that spare them from having to stem *xenophobic*, it removes the “unreasonable fear” element of a phobia and makes clear that they are taking a position against the aliens.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's science fiction anyway, let's coin a word:

> anterraphobic

(an- not + terra, of Earth + phobic)

Comment: _An-_ is only used before vowels (and _h_), though, and _Terra_ doesn't mean ‘of Earth’—it's just means ‘Earth’. The adjective is _Terran_; so it should just be _aterranophobic_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: And in any case, "terran" is based on a Latin adjective (which makes it slightly dubious to use either a combing form "terra-" or "terrano-") while "a-/an-" and "phobic" are from Greek, so it doesn't really fit together.

Answer (score -1):

[Specist?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specist)

Comment: It's more commonly called [speciesism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speciesism), and usually means favouring homo sapiens over other animals on *this* planet.

Comment: I prefer xenophobia/xenophobic, but DavRob60 didn't want that. So I went for a word that could mean what he wanted, especially since he noted the use of the word racist (discrimination based on race). Speciesism would be discrimination based on species, and he specified extraterrestrial SPECIES.

Comment: I certainly agree *xenphobia* is really the best word anyway. But *speciesism* has been used for some decades now with no particular implication of extraterrestrials being involved. In my experience it's often used by, for example, vegetarians, people against animal testing, etc. In short, its semantic reach has already ruled it out for the same reason OP doesn't like *xenophobia*.